# Highchart, Plot bands for each bar

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I need to show the design in highchart somewhat like the following code I found:

```js
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
};
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart:{
        type:'column',
        inverted:false,
    },
    credits:{enabled:false},
    exporting:{enabled:false},
    legend:{enabled:false},
    title:{text:''},
    xAxis:{
        tickLength:0,
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        labels:{style:{fontWeight:'bold'}}        
    },
    yAxis:{
        min:0,
        minPadding:0,
        maxPadding:0,
        tickColor:'#ccc',
        tickWidth:1,
        tickLength:3,
        gridLineWidth:0,
        endOnTick:true,
        title:{text: ''},
        labels:{
            y:10,
            style:{
                fontSize:'8px'
            },
            formatter:function(){
                if (this.isLast){
                    return this.value + ' %';
                }
                else{
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip:{
        enabled:true,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, .85)',
        borderWidth:0,
        shadow:true,
        style:{fontSize:'10px',padding:2},
        formatter:function() {
           return this.series.name + ": <strong>" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2) + "</strong>";
        }
    },
    plotOptions:{
        column:{
            color:'#000',
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0,
        },
        scatter:{
            marker:{
                symbol:'line',
                lineWidth:3,
                radius:8,
                lineColor:'#000'
            }
        }
    }
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container1'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 1']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'}},    
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:70,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:70,to:85,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:85,to:100,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[80]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[90],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container2'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 2']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:75,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:75,to:90,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:90,to:100,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[92]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[95],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container3'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 3']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:50,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:50,to:75,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:75,to:100,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[64]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[75],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container4'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 4']},
    yAxis:{
        max:1000,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'},formatter:function(){return this.value;}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:600,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:600,to:800,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:800,to:1000,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[970]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[850],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart5 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container5'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 5']},
    yAxis:{
        max:500,tickInterval:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'},formatter:function(){return this.value;}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:300,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:300,to:400,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:400,to:500,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[475]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[450],}]
});
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
    font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.7em;
}
p {
    margin:.5em 1em;
}
#container1, #container2, #container3, #container4, #container5{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container1" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div> 
<div id="container2" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
<div id="container3" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
<div id="container4" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
<div id="container5" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
```

See the same in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdHYt/390/)

In the above code, 5 charts are used separately, with bands for each chart.

But I need to implement the bands for *each bar* instead of each chart. Is there an option for this in highchart?

Comment: One way of doing this is by using rectangles. I used that approach to solve a similar problem. See documentation here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer and example here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-rect-on-chart/.

Comment: I inserted the code as a snippet in your question, as it is better to have the important elements in the question itself, not on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply specific gradient on plot bands to create `tricolor` effect.

DOCS Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vr1sz8yo/

Comment: Can we create the band dynamically?

Comment: Sure, you can create plot bands on `load` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) based on the values from your previous example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add band to each of the columns on load event of highcharts if chart is dynamic or else hard code it for static data(use different id,color etc)

[xAxis.plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands) reference

Here is dynamic example

```
 chart: {
  alignTicks: false,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      console.log(this.xAxis[0])
      var j = 0;
      var ticks = this.xAxis[0].paddedTicks;
      for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++) {
        if (i == 9) {
          j = 0;
        }
        this.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
          from: ticks[i] - .5,
          to: ticks[i] + .5,
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[j],
          id: 'plot-band-1' + i
        });

       j++;
      }
    }
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/Lbo45x0j/) demo